# Tools for testing tcl GUI in Linux

Tags: automated-testing, gui, unix

My question is related to this thread:
  [Typical software & tools short-list for *manual* QA specialist (tester) working environment](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5624/typical-software-tools-short-list-for-manual-qa-specialist-tester-working)

The answers to this question seemed to be mostly/entirely from a Windows viewpoint.  My company develops a backup app for UNIX environments and I'm looking for a way to automate the testing of actions in the GUI interface.  Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally Linux GUIs are just a thin layer over a command line application, consider testing the command line application separately than test the GUI using a mock application.

Answer (score 0):

Test the underlying code as mentioned by Rsf.

Consider using tcltest
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/tcltest.htm and
http://wiki.tcl.tk/14465

More specifically about the gui - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3771683/631619

Record and play  - http://wiki.tcl.tk/15726

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're wanting to automate (just clicking on certain places on the screen? Or actually creating a dialog that expects/interprets certain displays/alerts and then does something -- clicking or typing -- in response?) and the software that is providing your GUI -- check out [X11::GUITest](http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.28/GUITest.pm) or [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org).