# What are some best resources of self study for a beginner black-box tester?

Tags: manual-testing, tools

I have just started working as a manual/black-box tester in a QA team. I am currently learning about testing techniques/practices from others. What are some good resources which i can use to make a good foundation in software testing?

please link reference material including websites , blogs, free courses etc.

Comment: Do you want to learn about manual testing or automated testing?

Comment: Manual is covered under http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5624/8992

Comment: thanks Michael! i want to focus only on manual/functional testing as of now.

Comment: More generally you may find http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/3238/8992 helpful

Comment: ok then we'll want to close this in favor of the linked one which already has good info.  Please upvote and comment there so the activity puts it at the top of the list for more attention.